# Compare date ranges in ISO format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iso8601, daterangepicker

[Link to codeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-silence-g91r4?file=/src/index.js)

I have two date ranges, one from API and another from user input. Both are in ISO format.

date range from API:

```
dateStart 2019-04-01T03:04:00Z
dateStop 2019-04-01T03:05:00Z
```

date range from user input:

```
convertedDateFrom 2020-09-15T18:30:00.000Z
convertedDateTo 2020-09-21T18:30:00.000Z
```

I want to convert the `date range from user input` to `date range from API`. How can I achieve that?

```
EXPECTED: I want to compare the values two date-ranges and depending on that 
I will perform certain export functionality.
    The user input date-range could 
     - fall completely within the date-range of the API
    - or at least one of the date values could fall or overlap within the 
      date-range from the API.
```

should overlap the date range from the API.

this is my `date range picker handle()`

```
handleDatePickerChange = (setSelectedDayRange) => {
    console.log("initializing handleDatePickerChange()");
    console.log("setSelectedDayRange", setSelectedDayRange);
    // TODO
    // convert the dates
    let convertedDateFrom = moment(setSelectedDayRange.from).toISOString();
    console.log("convertedDateFrom", convertedDateFrom);

    let convertedDateTo = moment(setSelectedDayRange.to).toISOString();
    console.log("convertedDateTo", convertedDateTo);

    // compare dates
    // if(convertedDateFrom ===  )
    // check if data exists

    this.setState({
      selectedDayRange: setSelectedDayRange,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Whats your expected output here ? Its unclear!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping ohk. apologies for that. I've updated description with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you could use function `isBetween` provided by moment in this way:

```
// interval comes from API
let dateAPIFrom = moment().toISOString();
let dateAPITo = moment().add(2, "days").toISOString();

// user date interval
let convertedDateFrom = moment(setSelectedDayRange.from).toISOString();
let convertedDateTo = moment(setSelectedDayRange.to).toISOString();

if (
  moment(convertedDateFrom)
    .subtract(1, "month")
    .isBetween(dateAPIFrom, dateAPITo) &&
  moment(convertedDateTo)
    .subtract(1, "month")
    .isBetween(dateAPIFrom, dateAPITo)
) {

  //The user input date-range fall completely within the date-range of the API

} else if (
  moment(convertedDateFrom)
    .subtract(1, "month")
    .isBetween(dateAPIFrom, dateAPITo) ||
  moment(convertedDateTo)
    .subtract(1, "month")
    .isBetween(dateAPIFrom, dateAPITo)
) {

  //or at least one of the date values could fall or overlap within the date-range from the API.
 
}
```

`.subtract(1, "month")` because `moment({day: 19, month: 8, year: 2020}).toISOString()` returns always `month + 1`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-poitras-dqbwd?file=/src/index.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: @Giovani thanks. for some reason, but the if conditions don't seem to execute.

Comment: @NaumanTanwir yes you are right. This happens because `.toIsoString` returns always `month + 1` so you have to `.subtract(1, "month")` to `convertedDateFrom` and `convertedDateTo` and it works. I have updated codesandbox. Now I update my answer. Sorry for that :)

Comment: @LionelRowe f you try `moment().toISOString();` today, as month returns 8 (correct). If you try `moment(moment().toISOString())` returns 9 (month + 1)

Comment: @LionelRowe https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-poitras-dqbwd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LionelRowe `moment(moment({day: 19, month: 8, year: 2020}).toISOString())` returns 9 (we are talking about moment but the problem is not moment, the problem is the output of react-modern-calendar-datepicker!!!)

Comment: Quick question, can someone please explain my stupid mind why the `if conditions` do not work if I remove the `.subtract()` ? thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer: it's because of `react-modern-calendar-datepicker`. `DatePicker` returns an object like `{day: 19, month: 8, year: 2020}` and if you pass this object to moment, moment returns 19/9/2020 and not 19/8/2020 as expected. So I added `subtract(1, "month")`.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I've removed my comments as they stemmed from my lack of knowledge of `react-modern-calendar-datepicker`. Seems like it's a bug in the datepicker, not moment, as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

They're both ISO-8601 dates, which can be easily converted into native `Date` objects, which can be converted to a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. You don't need any complicated logic or even to use `moment` for this.

```js
/**
 * If result is negative, the first date is earlier
 * If result is positive, the second date is earlier
 * If result is 0, both dates are exactly the same
 */
const compareIsoDates = (isoString1, isoString2) => {
  return new Date(isoString1).valueOf() - new Date(isoString2).valueOf()
}

// result is -46106760000, meaning first date is earlier
console.log(compareIsoDates('2019-04-01T03:04:00Z', '2020-09-15T18:30:00.000Z'))

/**
 * strictly between (cannot be the same as start or end)
 * if you want to allow same as start and end, change to
 * >= and <= instead of > and <
 */
const isStrictlyBetween = (targetDate, [startDate, endDate]) => {
  return compareIsoDates(targetDate, startDate) > 0
    && compareIsoDates(targetDate, endDate) < 0
}

// true
console.log(isStrictlyBetween(
  '2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  ['2020-04-20T18:30:00Z', '2020-05-10T00:00:00Z']
))

// you can also use `compareIsoDates` a sort function to sort an array of
// ISO strings in ascending order (earliest to latest)
console.log([
  "1998-02-12T08:18:27.991Z",
  "2005-03-19T19:48:59.501Z",
  "1997-05-01T14:58:13.848Z",
  "2008-08-31T01:30:11.880Z",
  "2004-08-05T16:07:55.443Z"
].sort(compareIsoDates))
```

Answer (score 0):

A great thing about the ISO date formats is that they are sortable alphabetically.

This means that while you can convert it to a `Date` / `moment` / etc. you will get exactly the same results as comparing them as strings.

You can write for example Lionel's `compareISODates` function as:

```js
/**
 * If result is negative, the first date is earlier
 * If result is positive, the second date is earlier
 * If result is 0, both dates are exactly the same
 */
const compareISODates = (isoString1, isoString2) => {
  return isoString1.localeCompare(isoString2);
};
```

Or as another example, `convertedDateFrom/To` falls completely into `dateStart/End` you can simply check if

```js
convertedDateFrom >= dateStart && convertedDateTo <= dateEnd
```

Of course if you need more complicated logic you should use one of the Date libraries mentioned above.

Comment: You'll run into issues with this approach with timezones other than `Z` (including the timezone `+00:00`, which means the same as `Z`), and with comparing dates that do/don't have fractional second parts (as shown in the difference between API format and user input format in the OP). Ex: `'2010-10-10T10:10:10.000Z'.localeCompare('2010-10-10T10:10:10Z')` returns `-1`, but you want `0`.